# LESS / SASS / STYLUS Chrome Dev Tools and Firebug debugging

Tags: css, sass, firebug, less, stylus

I'm choosing a css pre-processor for some projects, and want to make sure it can be debugged in both Firebug and Chrome inspector (to see the actual lines in .less .scss .styl). Is it *currently* possible to set up chrome/ff debugging for these 3 pre-processors?

Comment: I see there is a Firefox extension call [FireSass](https://addons.mozilla.org/zh-CN/firefox/addon/firesass-for-firebug/). But no less ones AFAIK.

Comment: Stylus is on it's way: https://github.com/LearnBoost/stylus/pull/1129

Comment: Stylus "on it's way" usually means a few more months. :[

Answer (score 3):

For preprocessors that support CSS source maps, Chrome DevTools lets you live-edit your preprocessor source files in the Sources panel, and view the results without having to leave DevTools or refresh the page. When you inspect an element whose styles are provided by a generated CSS file, the Elements panel displays a link to the original source file, not the generated .css file.

To use this workflow, your CSS preprocessor must support CSS source maps, specifically the Source Map v3 proposal. The CSS source maps must be built along with the CSS files, so DevTools can map each CSS property to the correct location in the original source file (for example, .scss file).

You can read more info at https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/css-preprocessors

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else ends up here, to use source maps in Chrome for Sass, you need to use the `--sourcemap` flag to generate them first!

```
sass --watch --sourcemap --debug-in sass/screen.scss:screen.css
```

More info: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/tips-and-tricks#debugging-sass

The `--debug-info` flag will set the css up to work with FireSass.